# How can I cite an accepted conference paper but it hasn't been presented?

Tags: citations

My paper was accepted by a conference which is going to take place in November. However, before I go to present it, I need to cite it in another paper. Does anyone know how to cite an accepted but yet not presented conference paper in APA?

Answer (score 0):

Just cite it as a normal conference paper (with month and year as the time stamp). I assume that you are writing another paper that will undergo the review process. By the time you are done, the conference will have been given. Usually, conference papers are available immediately after and sometimes even before the conference. You want to check on this. If you are submitting you might want to include the old paper as additional material for the referees. The only problem would be if for some reason your conference paper is removed by the conference, e.g. because no author attended the conference.

If you are citing for something being published right now, then just say: "in Proceedings on the International Symposium on Biological Computing, November 2022 (to appear)". As always, you want to make finding the cited article as easy as possible, but with scholar.google.com, this is easy.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!